# Read data from Javascript dynamic input in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I need dynamic input fields for my node-js application. I need to populate a input text are for writing their cost names on a form. I found some javascript code on internet. It works perfectly but when i try to read data from body, i only have one value. What could be the reason?

Here is my javascript code;

```
$(function () {
  var max_fields = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
  var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
  var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

  var x = 1; //initlal text box count
  $(add_button).click(function (e) {
    //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if (x < max_fields) {
      //max input box allowed
      x++; //text box increment
      $(wrapper).append(
        '<div><input type="text" name="generalCostName[]" class="form-control"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'
      ); //add input box
    }
  });

  $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function (e) {
    //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent("div").remove();
    x--;
  });
});
```

here is the part of my ejs file;

```
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
   <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button><div>
   <input type="text" name="generalCostName[]" class="form-control"></div>
</div>
```

For example, i populate 2 more input fields and their values are "Test1","Test2" and  "Test3". When i submit values to the node-js side, on the console( console.log(req.body.generalCostName) ) i only have Test1 value. What could be the reason?

Comment: it seems like they have the same name. try to generate different name to each input. also you can send it as an object to the backend with ajax or fetch , post request and the body of the request will be all the input with the same class. if you need more help i can show you an example if it will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `formData` to send your dynamically added element to your backend `node.js`. We need to use jQuery `$.each` function to get all the values of the input you will added.

Once we have all the value we can append them to the `formData` which will send via `ajax` or `axios` to the `backend`.

I have limited the max fields added to 3 so for demo purposes but you can use as many as you like. As soon as you hit `submit` - the data will be stored in the formData and then you can do `POST` request to `node.js` where you can see all this coming.

**Demo:** (Shows all the inputs added and their value stored in the formData)

```js
$(function() {
  var max_fields = 3; //maximum input boxes allowed
  var wrapper = $(".input_fields_wrap"); //Fields wrapper
  var add_button = $(".add_field_button"); //Add button ID

  var x = 1; //initlal text box count
  $(add_button).click(function(e) {
    //on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if (x < max_fields) {
      //max input box allowed
      x++; //text box increment
      $(wrapper).append(
        '<div><input type="text" name="generalCostName" class="form-control"/><a href="#" class="remove_field">Remove</a></div>'
      ); //add input box
    }
  });

  $(wrapper).on("click", ".remove_field", function(e) {
    //user click on remove text
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).parent("div").remove();
    x--;
  });

});


//Send data to node.js
function sendData() {

  //initialize formData
  var formData = new FormData();
  
  //Get all value of dynamically added elements
  $('.form-control').each(function(index, item) {
    var val = $(item).val();
    //Append Data
    formData.append('value[]', val)
  });

  // Display the key/value pairs for formData
  for (var pair of formData.entries()) {
    console.log(pair[0] + ', ' + pair[1]);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="input_fields_wrap">
  <button class="add_field_button">Add More Fields</button>
  <div>
    <input type="text" name="generalCostName[]" class="form-control"></div>
</div>

<br>

<button onclick="sendData()">
  Submit
</button>
```